# @font-face css add custom font

Tags: css, wordpress, fonts, font-face

I have a wordpress theme and I want to add a custom font. I have added a "fonts" folder within the theme file in which I put the font files.

Right now my css looks like this:

```
@font-face {
font-family: Brandon;
src: url('/domains/test.innerwhy.com/html/wp-content/themes/thefox/fonts/Brandon_bld.otf');
font-weight: normal;
}
h1 {
font-family: Brandon;
}
```

However, this doesn't seem to work and I don't understand why.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the console using your web browsers dev tools? This will give you an error if it can't find or load the font. Might be a good place to start.

Comment: `src: url('/domains/test.innerwhy.com/html/...` - that looks rather like a file system path (based on folder names), whereas it should be a (relative) URL. If you don’t know what the difference is, then that is the first thing you should go read up on.

Answer (score 1):

By looking at that I can only suggest that you check that the path is correct from css file. it would also be good to set a fall back in case that font fails to load too. You might also be missing the font file type that's supported by your device.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because of the src path is wrong. "/domains/test.innerwhy.com/html/wp-content/themes/thefox/fonts/Brandon_bld.otf"

You can download font files locally and use like this:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'Montserrat-Regular';
src: url('../fonts/montserrat-regular-webfont.eot');
src: url('../fonts/montserrat-regular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('../fonts/montserrat-regular-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
     url('../fonts/montserrat-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
     url('../fonts/montserrat-regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype');
```

}

Comment: When I try this the console of the dev tool says: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: You can download from this link. After that generate web font online. https://github.com/piamancini/landing/tree/master/fonts